# Google storage is out of space

Tags: google-drive, google-plus

I deleted all my photos from Google+ Photo, but it still don't show space is free. I also deleted all from my recycle bin in Google Drive, GMail and Photos recycle. How can I to fix this issue?

[image: space usage]

May be there are some google employees? Google don't provide any support. This thread: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/drive/EzNsIqKzv6U was still don't answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see, Google calculates storage free space by cron or something like this: after few days, when all photos and trash was cleaned, I see only 4 Gb from my GMail.

I also deleted some interesting "empty" albums with 1 photo (and no photos in it) by PicasaWeb site. May be it also helps me.

Answer (score 1):

Did you empty the [Trash](https://plus.google.com/photos/trash) in your Google Photos? They'll automatically go in 60 days, but you can force them to be deleted permanently before that. I expect that items in your Trash will continue to count against your limit.

The same should be true of your [Google Drive Trash](https://drive.google.com/#trash) as well as the [Trash label in Gmail](https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#trash).

Comment: Yes, I wrote it in my question

Answer (score 0):

For info on Google Drive storage, see https://support.google.com/drive/answer/6558?hl=en&ref_topic=2375005

In particular, it's important to know that some files don't count towards your storage limits, e.g.:

> Google+ Photos: Only photos over 2048x2048 pixels and videos longer than 15 minutes count toward your storage limit.

By default, G+ resizes photos to fit this limit.

> Google Docs, Sheets, Slides, Presentations, Drawings, etc. don't count
>
> Files shared with you never count toward your storage on the web

So deleting these files won't help towards your storage limit.

You can sort Drive docs by size, then delete some (to the trash), then permanently delete them.

Gmail attachments may accumulate a lot of storage usage. You can search Gmail for "has:attachment" to find them all, then delete ones you don't need that are large. You can't just remove an attachment from a message or remove a message from a thread. You have to delete the entire thread.

Support site: https://support.google.com/drive/answer/4431192?hl=en&ref_topic=14951

Comment: I deleted all photos.

Comment: @GuyFawkes Did you understand that deleting all the "small" photos doesn't help towards your storage limit?

Answer (score 0):

Just got the same issue.

Maybe it was coincidence, but right after I clicked the 'Report this issue' link under 'Google Drive on the web' > 'Users getting a "not enough storage" error' on
https://support.google.com/drive/known-issues/2458941?hl=en&ref_topic=14951

the storage space started to get recalculated and I have free space again.